Need a line equation that is fixed at the origin and is horizontally asymptotic to a given value
I need an equation for a line that remains fixed at origin (0, 0) but is horizontally asymptotic with value c; Preferably in slope-intercept form
e.g. something along the lines of y = (x - a)/x + (c - 1)
Does anyone know any ready examples that meet these criteria?

A line (linear function) has a constant slope, so it's not possible for any line to be horizontally asymptotic to some constant $ c $ unless $y=c,$ but that function doesn't pass through $(0,0)$ unless $c=0$. However, if you just want a function that is not a line, you can use $ y = c(1 - e^{-x})$. This function returns $y=0$ at $x=0$ and approaches $c$ as $x$ goes to infinity.
